# Pandas, recording a continuous average

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, average

I'm writing a program takes in data that is linked with time, I want to be able to average the values of the data if there are more than one points of data per minute. The data points also have different devices that they record data for and cannot be mixed. I'm using a pandas dataframe and the points of data coming in are almost never for the same column continually, so I cannot add them as they come in and average them with a stored counter later, if I want it to run quickly. Any Ideas on how to keep the average recorded as I go?

```
    def add_data(self, x, whitelist, time_zone):
        y, mo, d, h, mi, s = self.parseDateTime(x['date'])   
        date = (dt.datetime(y, mo, d, h, mi) + dt.timedelta(hours=self.time_zones[self.time_zone])).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
        key = x['keys']
        val = x['val']
        if (val != 'NaN'):
            if(key in whitelist):
                self.dfOut[key][date] = val
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your dataset, preferentially as text

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clean your data first and possibly create a new column if the data ready to be analyzed, and then include some logics to compare where data should calculate average or not in your algorithm, could you share a sample of you data and any algorithm you may have.

Comment: I cannot share a sample of the data at the moment, due to the data belonging to the company I work for, but I can give a generic template. The program ultimately formats all of the data that we receive from our products. The beginning data starts off as a csv with three columns of data. TIME, PRODUCT_NAME, VALUE RECORDED. The data ends up in a format of time labeling all of the rows and the product names labeling the columns.